# Flutter Sqflite - Delete database when user sign out

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite

I'm using a Sqflite-database for my app to store user-data. The problem is when the user sign out, I wanna delete the database in order to avoid conflict if user sign in with another account e.g. I don't wanna present the earlier users data on the new sign in right?

So when I delete the database it seems to work fine, but when user sign in again I get this error below:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'query' was called on null.
```

Receiver: null

I guess the problem is that _databaseVersion is always 1, so I wonder how I could solve this problem?

**CLASS**

```
    class DatabaseHelper {
  static final _databaseName = "MyDatabase.db";
  static final _databaseVersion = 1;

  static final table = 'my_table';

  static final columnId = '_id';
  static final columnCity = 'city';
  static final columnAge = 'age';
  static final columnAds = 'ads';

  // make this a singleton class
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  // only have a single app-wide reference to the database
  static Database _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    // lazily instantiate the db the first time it is accessed
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  // this opens the database (and creates it if it doesn't exist)
  _initDatabase() async {
    print("init database");
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, _databaseName);
    await openDatabase(path, version: _databaseVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  // SQL code to create the database table
  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            $columnCity TEXT,
            $columnAge TEXT,
            $columnAds INT
          )
          ''');

    ///NOTE: columnAds 0 = true, 1 = false
  }

  // Helper methods

  // Inserts a row in the database where each key in the Map is a column name
  // and the value is the column value. The return value is the id of the
  // inserted row.
  Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(table, row);
  }

  // All of the rows are returned as a list of maps, where each map is
  // a key-value list of columns.
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllRows() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.query(table);
  }

  // All of the methods (insert, query, update, delete) can also be done using
  // raw SQL commands. This method uses a raw query to give the row count.
  Future<int> queryRowCount() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(
        await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table'));
  }

  // We are assuming here that the id column in the map is set. The other
  // column values will be used to update the row.
  Future<int> update(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    int id = row[columnId];
    return await db.update(table, row, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  // Deletes the row specified by the id. The number of affected rows is
  // returned. This should be 1 as long as the row exists.
  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete(table, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<bool> deleteDb() async {
    bool databaseDeleted = false;

    try {
      Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, _databaseName);
      await deleteDatabase(path).whenComplete(() {
        databaseDeleted = true;
      }).catchError((onError) {
        databaseDeleted = false;
      });
    } on DatabaseException catch (error) {
      print(error);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }

    return databaseDeleted;
  }

  Future closeDb() async {
    var dbClient = await instance.database;
    dbClient.close();
  }
```

Comment: have you found any solution? if yes then please post a valid answer, everyone seems facing this issue might your answer will help me and also others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your helper class is always using `_databaseVersion = 1`.

I think, that's the reason why the version is always `1`.

Answer (score -1):

Usually you don't want to delete the Database itself. If so, you need to create the database again when the app starts otherwise there is no query to run the db related functions hence the error occurs.
My suggestion would be to delete the columns(Table) in the database.

```
// Delete LoginResponse records

Future<int> deleteLoginResponse(int id) async {
  final db = await dbProvider.database;
  var result = await db.delete(loginTABLE, where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);

  return result;
}
```